# Bable in only producing js files(in dist folder) and not other files in project directory(like html,css..). I am using "build":"babel source -d dist"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Bable in only producing js files(in dist folder) and not other files in project directory(like html,css..). I am using "build":"babel source   -d dist".

Comment: That's exactly what Babel does: it transpiles JavaScript code and outputs it to some location (specified by `-d` flag). Babel is not concerned with any other type of file in your project. Look into solutions like [_webpack_](https://webpack.js.org/) if you want to process all types of files.

Comment: "babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files" worked.

Answer (score 1):

Babel is not an application bundler, it's a JavaScript compiler. You could either add a script to copy non-JS files to the dist folder, or use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) for your build.

Comment: "babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files" worked. 

One more query, I am unable to export/import in ES6, it says require is not defined with babel transpiler. What should I do...